# Point moving after command but not in debugger

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have been trying to modify [vlf](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/VLF) so that normally scrolling reloads additional portions of the file when the points gets near the edge of the current batch.  That much is working, but I am experiencing a strange problem.

I am implementing the reloading through advice like this.

```
(defadvice scroll-up (after vlf-scroll-up activate)
  "In `vlf-mode', scrolling will reload sections to avoid getting
  near the edge of the block."

  (vlf-force-near-center))
```

`vlf-force-near-center` is a function that I wrote to reload the file if necessary.  It works correctly, and a `message` at the end indicates that the point is in the middle of the new batch.  However, sometime between when the function finishes and the display finishes refreshing, the point moves to near the beginning of the buffer, but not all the way.  It appears to have gone to the top of the file and then moved the point to the center of the screen.

To try to figure out what is happening, I did `(debug-on-entry 'vlf-force-near-center)`.  Stepping through the function, it worked as expected.  However, after it finished (I used `c` to let it run to completion), the point stayed where it was supposed to be.

I looked at `post-command-hook` and `after-change-functions` and both are nil.

I have a complicated .emacs, but the problem is also present if I run emacs by

```
emacs -Q --load ~/emacs/vlf.el very-large-file.txt
```

So I have two questions, that would give a direct and an indirect solution to my problem.

1. Why the point is moving?
2. Why does the problem not occur when I run through the debugger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling in Emacs is tricky business: Emacs's redisplay normally scrolls (i.e. moves window-start) automatically so as to keep point within view, so when running an explicit scroll command there's sometimes a conflict between the scroll command itself (which might force point to move so as to stay within view) and the auto-scroll that tries instead to move window-start rather than moving point.

Running under the debugger will often affect this behavior by causing various intermediate redisplays so that the "real" redisplay (the one which would also have happened without debugging) ends up running differently because point (and/or the window-start) has already been moved by some earlier redisplay.

Maybe this is the problem into which you're bumping.

Of course, maybe not.  It's hard to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new package called [vlfi](https://github.com/m00natic/vlfi) which extends vlf. One of the features is automatic scrolling of batches. The functions `vlfi-next-batch`/`vlfi-prev-batch` display the appropriate batch, then, similarly to what you did, an advice is used to call them while scrolling the file.